# Listen for Azure scale set events in js

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I'm writing a matchmaker in js that creates/deletes/starts/stops vm instances in a Azure scale set.

I need to listen for events when the state or the health of the vms change. There are a lot of concepts like EventHub, event grid, monitoring, etc. which I already checked out.

Since I'm new to the azure topic I'm not sure what to use nor if it can be accomplished to fit my needs.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

So if you see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-portal) you will see in that screen a Notify tab. In this tab you can use the webhook option so whenever a scale out\in event will occur then this webhook can be called and then you can take it from that point onwards in your code.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks